# In Corda how can we get the Node database connection string in the API

Tags: corda

I am trying to get the the JDBCsession connection url from the node into my API using a flow. I could get the flow to return the url using  serviceHub.jdbcSession().metaData.url. However this returns url of the form "jdbc:h2:file:D:\Anshulee Projects\Corda\XXX-corda-network\build\nodes\Provider/persistence" and while a query using serviceHub.jdbcSession within the node works well, any attempt to connect to this url via the h2 Console or another created JDBCSession etc results in a Database in use exception. How can i get the the same connection string as seen in the crash shell? This one  jdbc:h2:tcp://172.18.148.97:9190/node?

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to retrieve the JDBC TCP connection string.

However, you can statically set the node's H2 address and port in the node's `node.conf` file, and use these static values for the frontend.

As of Corda 3, you configure this in the `node.conf` file using:

`h2port=12345`

In Corda 4, the configuration option will have changed to:

`h2Settings { address: "localhost:12345" }`

Comment: Thanks @Joel. Would just like to add that for corda 3.x it should be h2port and not h2Port ( p is not capitalized). Got this answer from your team  member in corda ledger Slack and it worked :-)